# How to plot contour plots of R0 against two parameters?

Tags: plotting, graphics, systems-biology

I am working on an epidemiological model and I would like to know how to plot contour plots of **R0** (basic reproduction number) against two given parameters using Mathematica. An example contour plot is given below.

[image]

The values of the parameters (except beta and gamma) of my model and the formula for R0 are given below.

```
c = 0.01
theta = 0.2778
p = 0.05
phi = 0.95
epsilon = 0.084
delta = 0.011
mu = 0.000027

R0 = (epsilon*c*beta*theta*(mu+(1-phi)*p))/(mu*(mu+p)*(mu+epsilon)*(mu+gamma+delta))
```

I wish to draw the contour plot of R0 against the two parameters **beta** and **gamma** which could both vary between 0 and 1. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Try: ContourPlot[R0, {gamma, 0, 1}, {beta, 0, 1}]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

c = 0.01;
theta = 0.2778;
p = 0.05;
phi = 0.95;
epsilon = 0.084;
delta = 0.011;
mu = 0.000027;

R0 = (epsilon*c*beta*
     theta*(mu + (1 - phi)*p))/(mu*(mu + p)*(mu + epsilon)*(mu + 
       gamma + delta));

ContourPlot[R0, {beta, 0, 1}, {gamma, 0, 1},
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {β, γ}),
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic,
   LegendLabel -> Placed[HoldForm[R0], Bottom]]]
```

[image]

**Compared with the example shown in the question, R0 has much larger values.**